# select datetime in gridview and change next textbox value upon date selection in gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Scenario is i have a date time column in grid view, upon selection on  date time column i need to show calculated value in next column's  text box in gridview

i am not able to calculate value on basis of date selection, although i am able to select the date through jquery and place it in textbox. but it is not changing the next textbox value upon basis of selection.
code is as under

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Issue Date">
        <ItemStyle Width="140px" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtIssueDate" runat="server" Width="110px" Text='<%#Eval("RequirementIssueDate") %>'
                ReadOnly="true" class="Calender" OnTextChanged="txtIssueDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <img id="imgIssueDate" src="../KelshawImages/calender.png" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Expiration Date">
        <ItemStyle Width="140px" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiration" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RequirementExpirationDate") %>'
                ReadOnly="true" class="Calender" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>
            <img src="../KelshawImages/calender.png" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I think that if you put the ReadOnly attribute on the control you will not be able to modify it in the textchanged event.  Try removing the ReadOnly=True attribute and simply add the HTML disabled attribute to the control and give it a try.

Comment: I tried that, but its not working... any other idea about that